# C# Testing Multiple Proxies

Tags: c#, multithreading, proxy

I've been scratching my head about this. I'm wondering how I can test multiple proxies at once, I know how to test one at a time but that takes alot of time.
I'm using this code to test a proxy

```
    public bool testProxy( string proxy, int port )
    {
        try
        {
            WebClient web = new WebClient();
            web.Proxy = new WebProxy( proxy, port);
            web.DownloadString("http://www.google.com/ncr");
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Now how would I test them with multithreading or whatever I need to use?
Because at the moment I'm doing this when a button is pressed, which is time consuming

```
        if (proxy_list.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < proxy_list.Count; i++)
            {
                string Proxy = proxy_list[i];
                string[] vars = Proxy.Split( ':' );
                if (vars.Length == 2)
                {
                    proxy = vars[0];
                    port = int.Parse(vars[1]);
                    if ( !testProxy( proxy, port ) )
                    {
                        proxy_list.RemoveAt(i);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    proxy_list.RemoveAt(i);
                }
                textBox3.Text = proxy_list.Count.ToString();
                this.Refresh();
            }
        }
```

Test proxy function

```
    public void testProxy(string proxy, int port, int listpos)
    {
        try
        {
            WebClient web = new WebClient();
            web.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxy, port);
            web.DownloadString("http://www.google.com/ncr");
        }
        catch
        {
            proxy_list.RemoveAt(listpos);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (multithread)

```
        if (proxy_list.Count > 0)
        {
        for (int i = 0; i < proxy_list.Count; i++)
        {
            string Proxy = proxy_list[i];
            string[] vars = Proxy.Split( ':' );
            if (vars.Length == 2)
            {
                proxy = vars[0];
                port = int.Parse(vars[1]);

            Thread TestProxy = new Thread(testProxy( proxy, port, i));
            TestProxy.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                proxy_list.RemoveAt(i);
            }
            textBox3.Text = proxy_list.Count.ToString();
            this.Refresh();
        }
    }



    public bool testProxy( string proxy, int port, int listpos )
    {
    try
    {
        WebClient web = new WebClient();
        web.Proxy = new WebProxy( proxy, port);
        web.DownloadString("http://www.google.com/ncr");
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        proxy_list.RemoveAt(listpos);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering so quickly. I tried this and I experienced some problems with this part
    Thread TestProxy = new Thread( testProxy(proxy, port, i) );
    TestProxy.Start();

It first said it couldn't convert from bool to 'System.Threading.ParameterizedStart' then I changed it to void, it said the same thing, but with void instead of bool

Comment: @user3528008 you used private void testProxy( string proxy, int port, int listpos ) ?

Comment: nope, public void testPorxy( string proxy, int port, int listpos )